# My SQL Server database is not showing for Azure backups?

Tags: sql-server, azure, asp.net-core

When setting up backups within Azure, I get the following for the database portion:

> No supported connection strings of type SQL Database or MySQL found configured in app.

This is a `ASP.NET CORE 1.0` web app, and I have an instance of SQL Server and a SQL Database setup.

In the `App Settings`, it allows me to add connection strings. I have the following:

- **Connection String Name**: ConnectionString
- **Value**: Server=tcp:*******.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Staging;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=*******;Password=*******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
- **Type**: SQLServer
- **Slot Setting**: Unchecked/False

When navigating to the app, and choosing backups, my database is not showing and I get the message noted above. This is the same connection string I use within the app itself.

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: What type of SQL Server login is the `User ID` associated with? If it's a `public`-role user then it might not have the necessary backup permissions.

Comment: Please clarify exactly which feature of Azure you're referring to? Backing-up a web-application is different to backing up a database. You're using Azure SQL so you get backups for free, built-in to the service - so I'm not sure why you're trying to set-up another backup system for your database.

Comment: @Dai It's a server admin. Has access to all.

Comment: @Dai I'm aware of the backups built into the service, but you can select the app and choose backups, and have the webapp and selected database on a specific schedule. So if I select resources, choose my app, scroll down and click backup. Click configure backup, it allows me to set a schedule and also include a database with it, storing it within the azure storage container of my choice.

Comment: You think this is pointless and I should rely on the built-in service? I suppose that's okay and I could use point in time recovery, but I still do not understand why it isn't displaying as an option. New to Azure. Thanks for the help @Dai.

Comment: One more thing to add. If I view the SQL databases and click on Available Backups, this is empty, yet I can restore based on PiTR. So trying to understand the usage between the two (i.e. automated backup - built in, vs scheduled and stored in container). Pardon my ignorance.